# php mysql connect and create table with no error but no data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, scrape

I was able to connect to mysql db and create a table but there is no data and would like to know what i am missing or doing wrong? I have post my function code below. My echo count is confirmed and I also checked my Poems.csv to ensure they are not blank.

```
function writeQuotestoDb() {
  $input_csv = fopen( "Poems.csv", "r" );
  $author_names = array();
  $poem_names = array();
  $poem_urls = array();

  while (($columns = fgetcsv($input_csv, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    array_push( $author_names, $columns[0] );
    array_push( $poem_names,  $columns[1] );
    array_push( $poem_urls,  $columns[2] );
  }
  fclose( $input_csv );

  $dbh = mysql_connect( 'localhost', 'root', '' );
  mysql_select_db( 'test', $dbh );
  mysql_query("CREATE TABLE  IF NOT EXISTS `poem2` (
             `id` INT( 20 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
             `author_name` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
              `poem_name` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
              `poem_text` text,
              `poem_url` varchar(1024) DEFAULT NULL
             ) ENGINE = MYISAM");
    mysql_query("TRUNCATE `poem2`");     
    for ( $i=0; $i<count($author_names); $i++ ) {
        $poems[$i] = substr($poems[$i],7,(strlen($poems[$i])-14));
        $poems[$i] = str_replace('"','',$poems[$i]);
        $query = 'INSERT INTO `poem2` VALUES ( NULL,"' . $author_names[$i] . '", "' . $poem_names[$i].'","' . $poem_urls[$i] .'")';
        mysql_query($query);

    }
    echo count($author_names)." rows....successfully db updated";
 }
```

Comment: After the last mysql_query($query); add var_dump(mysql_error()); and see what's the error.

Comment: here is the result 
string(47) "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1" string(47) "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1" 
15038 rows....successfully db updated

Comment: Check the variables that you insert to your database to see whether they contain values or not.

Comment: how do i check that? Since i am getting data from csv into the sql db i made sure there are data in csv as they are just scraped data from the site

Comment: The error itself says what is wrong with the query. You are missing `poem_text` from your insert query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing poem_text from your insert query. You can use the updated code below:

```
function writeQuotestoDb() {
  $input_csv = fopen( "Poems.csv", "r" );
  $author_names = array();
  $poem_names = array();
  $poem_urls = array();

  while (($columns = fgetcsv($input_csv, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    array_push( $author_names, $columns[0] );
    array_push( $poem_names,  $columns[1] );
    array_push( $poem_urls,  $columns[2] );
    array_push( $poem_text,  $columns[3] ); // If columns[3] does not exists you can just  use array_push( $poem_text,  '' );
  }
  fclose( $input_csv );

  $dbh = mysql_connect( 'localhost', 'root', '' );
  mysql_select_db( 'test', $dbh );

  mysql_query("CREATE TABLE  IF NOT EXISTS `poem2` (
             `id` INT( 20 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
             `author_name` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
              `poem_name` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
              `poem_text` text,
              `poem_url` varchar(1024) DEFAULT NULL
             ) ENGINE = MYISAM");
    mysql_query("TRUNCATE `poem2`");     
    for ( $i=0; $i<count($author_names); $i++ ) {
        $poems[$i] = substr($poems[$i],7,(strlen($poems[$i])-14));
        $poems[$i] = str_replace('"','',$poems[$i]);
        $query = 'INSERT INTO `poem2`(`author_name`, `poem_name`, `poem_text`, `poem_url`) VALUES ( "' . $author_names[$i] . '", "' . $poem_names[$i] . '", "' . $poem_text[$i] . '","' . $poem_urls[$i] .'")';
        mysql_query($query);

    }
    echo count($author_names)." rows....successfully db updated";
 }
```

If you don't want to insert `poem_text` then just use the following insert statement instead of your original insert query.

```
 $query = 'INSERT INTO `poem2`(`author_name`, `poem_name`, `poem_url`) VALUES ( "' . $author_names[$i] . '", "' . $poem_names[$i] . '","' . $poem_urls[$i] .'")';
```